# Read array in php?

Tags: php, functions, user-meta

I'm trying to add some custom user meta on the registeration. For example, I have field to set a fruit :

```
function some_fruits($fruit= false) {
    $fruits= array();
    $fruits['1'] = 'Apple';
    $fruits['2'] = 'Banana';
    $fruits['3'] = 'Apricot';
    if ($fruit) {
        return $fruits[$fruit];
    } else {
        return $fruits;
    }
}
```

But when I call this field with

```
$display_fruit = get_user_meta($user_id, 'fruit', true);
```

it displays **1** instead of **Apple**. How can I solve this ?

Comment: And how do you set that meta field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest way would be something like this:

```
$fruit_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'fruit', true); //returns 1
$display_fruit = some_fruits($fruit_id); //will return 'Apple'
```

Comment: Do not bash self to head for too long. This happens awfuly a lot in my own code :)